# How to give permission to a role to cancel user accounts of some roles?

Tags: users

I have 3 roles in my site: **administrators**, **editor**, **clients**

I need to give permissin to the **editor** rol to cancel users account with of the **clients** role.

Can I do this?

Comment: by cancel do you mean block the account or delete the user account altogether?

Comment: yes, that's what i need